# Android Listview - GetView applies changes to items i don't want

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview adapter

adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems){

```
@Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                if(tv.getText().equals("TEXT1") || tv.getText().equals("TEXT2")) {
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                }
                return tv;
            }
        };
```

I want ONLY the items with the text : TEXT1 and TEXT2 to have their backgrounds changed.
No more items. Only those. But as i scroll more and more more items have their backgrounds changed, items that do NOT have the text TEXT1 or TEXT2.

How can i achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due of the recycling mechanism of the `ListView`:

to fix it you can "reset" the background colour it the if guard is false

```
if(tv.getText().equals("TEXT1") || tv.getText().equals("TEXT2")) {
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
} else {
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(OTHERCOLOR));
}
```

Comment: Unbelievable. This actually works. Thank you so much! :)